# Can I pause the sql server scheduler for couple of minutes automatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a job scheduled on sql server agent, running every minute.

I am thinking of 'pause' the job at 2,3 every hour (e.g. pause at 4:02, 4:03), then have it wake up again.

Could I do that automatically in sql server agent?

Comment: Better check time in your sceduled job/script and do not anything at "critical times". This way you don't have to pause sql scheduler at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start and stop sql server agent by command line.

for example in order to start SQL Server Agent use following command

```
net start "SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)"
```

Also you can execute dos command from sql server with `xp_cmdshell` command :

You can use following command to start or stop SQL Server Agent from SSMS:

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'net start "SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)"'
Exec xp_cmdshell 'net stop "SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)"'
```

You can have a **sql server job or windows task schedule** in order to stop Agent automatically in your schedule. and have a **windows task schedule** in order to start Agent automatically.

Comment: Thanks but how could i automate this process?

Comment: Have the job that the scheduler is running check the time and then conditionally call the script given.